# ERROR 1075 there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. Help me determine how I can keep the foreign key of ReportID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

Why isn't this working?? I need the second auto_increment as I am using it as a primary key in another table. I want to have it so the offences can be directly related to the reports they are found in

```
Create table ReportsFiled (
    ReportID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DateandTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    VehicleID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    LicenseNumber VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    OffenceCommitted VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ReportStatement VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    constraint pkReportsFiled primary key (ReportID, VehicleID),
    constraint fkReportsFiledVehID foreign key (VehicleID) references Vehicles(VehicleID),
    constraint fkReportsFiledLicNum foreign key (LicenseNumber) references People(LicenseNumber)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB ; 

Insert into ReportsFiled 
(ReportID, DateandTime, VehicleID, LicenseNumber, OffenceCommitted, ReportStatement)
Values 
(NULL, '2019-01-20 10:30:00', 'FD13 5TY', 'WRIGY96543867FD4', 'Moderate Speeding', 'Speeding in a residential area, given points and fine appropriate to the nature of the offence'),
(NULL, '2019-03-12 16:30:00', 'FT17 8HU', 'BARTO87252867BO4', 'Dangerous driving and Moderate Speeding', 'Driving recklessly in a residential area and driving above the speed limit, 3 points and £350'),
(NULL, '2019-05-28 12:23:00', 'SJ12 J8S', 'SMITH54398866QW4', 'Dangerous driving', 'Taking a corner too fast with no indication, 3 points given but no fine issued'),
(NULL, '2019-01-01 11:21:00', 'FT17 8HU', 'BARTO87252867BO4', 'Moderate Speeding', 'Driving at 42mph in a 30mph zone, 3 points and a £200 fine'),
(NULL, '2019-03-30 14:26:00', 'QW15 X4U', 'SPENC32975368DW8', 'Driving dangerously under the influence of alcohol', 'Licence ban and £2,500 fine'),
(NULL, '2019-08-21 22:14:00', 'FT17 8HU', 'BARTO87252867BO4', 'Driving while using a mobile device', 'Driving using a mobile device, 6 points and £500 fine') ;

Create table Offences (
    OffenceID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    OffenceStatement VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    MaximumFine VARCHAR(100),
    ReportID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    constraint pkOffences primary key (OffenceID, ReportID),
    constraint fkOffencesReID foreign key (ReportID) references ReportsFiled(ReportID)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

Insert into Offences
(OffenseID, OffenceStatement, MaximumFine, ReportID)
Values
(NULL, 'Moderate Speeding', '3-6 points and £0-£200 fine', NULL),
(NULL, 'Driving under the influence of alcohol', 'Licence ban and £2,500 fine', NULL),
(NULL, 'Extreme Speeding', 'Licence ban and £2,000 fine', NULL),
(NULL, 'Dangerous driving', '3 points and £0-£500', NULL),
(NULL, 'Driving while using a mobile device', '6 points and £500 fine', NULL) ;
```

Comment: Your data structure does not make sense.  If `ReportId` is unique, just use it as the primary key.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I would have thought that `ReportID` would be defined as auto increment in the other table.

Comment: *"Why isn't this working?? I need the second auto_increment "* i don't see a second auto_increment used in the code ? Also i doubt that that SQL would give that error we need to have the table structure off `ReportsFiled` aswell if it errors then the `foreign key` is the cause of that..

Comment: .... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/53bBNmppynJHnBsty2e2Bg/1 .. But like @GordonLinoff suggested, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help for proving sample data and desired results as it indeed looks a bit odd what you are trying here..

Comment: I have edited the text to try to clarify my aims

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mixing the concept of *primary key* and *foreign key* here.

The auto_incremented primary key gives you a unique integer id for each record.

The foreign key defines a relation where each value in the referring column of a table must be present in the referred column of another table. Foreign key columns are *not* auto_incremented. The referred column may be.

For your design to make sense (and to be accepted by the MySQL engine), you would need to make the auto-incremented column of each table the primary key, and define proper foreign keys.

Consider:

```
create table ReportsFiled (
    -- primary key
    ReportID int(10) not null primary key auto_increment,
    DateandTime datetime not null,
    VehicleID varchar(10) not null,
    LicenseNumber varchar(16) not null,
    OffenceCommitted varchar(255) not null,
    ReportStatement varchar(255) not null,
    -- foreign key to the Vehicle table
    constraint fkReportsFiledVehID
        foreign key (VehicleID) references Vehicles(VehicleID),  
    -- foreign key to People table
    constraint fkReportsFiledLicNum
        foreign key (LicenseNumber) references People(LicenseNumber)
) engine = InnoDB; 


create table Offences (
    -- primary key
    OffenceID int(10) not null auto_increment primary key
    OffenceStatement varchar(255) not null, 
    MaximumFine varchar(100),
    ReportID int(10) not null auto_increment,
    -- foreign key to People table
    constraint fkOffencesReID
        foreign key (ReportID) references ReportsFiled(ReportID)
) engine = InnoDB ;
```

Notes:

1. I am suspicious about the the foreign key to `People(LicenseNumber)`: is `LicenseNumber` the primary key of table `People`? If not, then it be aware that this column must at least be indexed (either by itself, or in the first position of a composite index). Or just consider referencing the primary key of `People` instead, which seems to be your intent here: you can always retrieve the license number with a join when needed.
2. The referring and referred column *must* have the same datatype